# Issue with text underline on mouseover

Tags: css

I'm trying to custmomize the navigation menu of a wordpress theme to have the links underlined on mouse over.

It works fine, except for the menu item which has sub-menu item. For this one (called "Test page"), the line is placed **above** the text and not **below** the next.

You can see it live [here](http://testsnas.be-pixel.com/)

How can I fix this issue?

Many thanks,

Looks bad for the link which has sub-menu items:

[image]

Looks good for the links with no sub-items:

[image]

```
/* Style the primary menu items */
#top-menu-nav > ul > li {
    padding-right:25px;
}

#top-menu-nav > ul > li > a {
    color: #000;
font-weight: 600;
    position:relative
}

#top-menu-nav > ul > li > a:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 18px;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: #90BAD4; /* underline color */
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

/* Style the primary menu items on hover */
#top-menu-nav > ul > li > a:hover {
    color:#00171f;
    opacity:1;
}

#top-menu-nav > ul > li > a:hover:after {
    width:100%;
    margin-left:-50%;
}

/* Style the active primary menu item */
#top-menu > li.current-menu-item > a,
#top-menu > li.current-menu-item > a:hover {
    color: #90BAD4;

}

#top-menu > li.current-menu-item > a:after {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is the `top` property from this selector:

```
/* Dropdown Arrows */
#top-menu .menu-item-has-children > a:first-child:after, #et-secondary-nav .menu-item-has-children > a:first-child:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; /* This one */
    right: 0;
    font-family: "ETmodules";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 800;
   content: "3";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However and do not find a way to fix my issue, do you?

Comment: Removing that line (`top: 0;`) works in my tests. Doesn't it?